# Using import for modules in NodeJS causes type errors

Tags: typescript

TSLint warns against using the `var` keyword in TypeScript, so I have been using `import` when importing modules. However, when I do this for local modules, it gives me an error when I tried to use the module.

In a file `routes/main.ts` I have:

```
import express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => { ... });

module.exports = router;
```

In `app.ts` I have:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/main.d.ts" />
import express = require("express");
...
import routes = require("./routes/main");
let app = express();
app.use(routes); // The type error is here.
...
```

Using `import routes` causes the following type error when I use it with `app.use(routes);`:

```
app.ts(36,13): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof ".../source/server...'
is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp'.
```

To fix this I can cast it to a particular type:

```
app.use(<express.Router>routes);
```

But there are places where type casting is not as clean. I can switch to using the var keyword when I import the module:

```
var routes = require("./routes/main");
let app = express();
app.use(routes); // No errors.
```

But is there a way to satisfy both the compiler and tslint? Or should I not use the `"no-var-requires": true` setting in tslint when using the CommonJS module style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `var`.
You can replace `module.exports = router;` with `export = router;` in routes/main.ts.
You have misunderstood the usage of `app.use`. You should use `app.use("/", routes)`.